# How to escape all unescaped slashes in Python

Tags: python, regex

I have a partially escaped path in Python like so:

```
path = "C:\\Temp\\\\TestEmpty" # Actual value = C:\Temp\\TestEmpty
```

I would like to have all slashes double like so:

```
escapedpath = "C:\\\\Temp\\\\TestEmpty" # Actual value = C:\\Temp\\TestEmpty
```

I started with some regex

```
escapedpath = re.sub("[a-zA-Z0-9 _:-](\\)[a-zA-Z0-9 _:-]", "\\\\", path)
```

...but of course this removes the character before and after the `\\`s

How could this be done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
result = re.sub(r"""(?x)
    (?<!\\)     # Make sure that there is no backslash before the current position
    \\          # Match a backslash
    (?=         # only if...
     (?:\\\\)*  # an even number of backslashes follows (including zero)
     (?!\\)     # and no further backslashes follow after that
    )           # (End of lookahead assertion)""", 
    r"\\\\", subject)
```

only replaces backslashes if the number of consecutive backslashes at this point is odd.

Comment: This is great, I've added an extra \ to the replace string to make it work.

Comment: @James: Great. I just noticed that error myself; seems to be a bug of RegexBuddy. I'll look into this.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a regex for this, if you just do a simple string replace to double all the backslashes followed by another string replace to undouble the ones that were already doubled then you get where you wanted to go:

```
>>> path = "C:\\Temp\\\\TestEmpty"
>>> path.replace('\\','\\\\').replace(r'\\\\', r'\\')
'C:\\\\Temp\\\\TestEmpty'
```

Alternatively undouble the doubled ones first then double all backslashes:

```
>>> path.replace('\\\\', '\\').replace('\\', '\\\\')
'C:\\\\Temp\\\\TestEmpty'
```

Comment: This is quite neat, I'm honestly not sure which is the better answer - the regex could be faster because it's one function rather than 2 replaces but I'm not sure.

Comment: You could try timing it to find out, but whichever is faster I find the string replace a bit less headache inducing.

Answer (score 0):

I use the following combination to sidestep a bit:

```
escaped_path = re.sub( r'(\\)+', '/', path).replace('/', '\\')
```

*(It has the added benefit of basic sanitation of paths someone (me) may have entered incorrectly by being greedy in replacing backslashes.)*